# What's the difference between these answers in this example?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, meaning-in-context

___________, the meeting began.
A. All of us seated
B. All of us had taken the seats
C. All of us have been seated
D. All of us having seated

The answer according to the book is A but I still don't understand the difference between them, please kindly explain it to me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sadly, *none of these are correct*.

A. All of us seated, the meeting began.
B. All of us had taken the seats, the meeting began.
C. All of us have been seated, the meeting began.
D. All of us having seated, the meeting began.

They all would need to be modified to be correct. For example:

A. ***With*** all of us seated, the meeting began.
B. ***After*** all of us had taken the seats, the meeting began.
C. ***When*** all of us have been seated, ***then*** the meeting ***can begin***.
D. ***With*** all of us having seated, the meeting began. (This one is a bit of a stretch - better as *Having seated ourselves, ...*).

I suspect what they might have been looking for is agreement in the tense. As *began* is the simple past / imperfect tense, the phrase that also has simple past is ***A. All of us seated***, as the verb *to seat* conjugates as *seat* / *seated* / *seated*.

A. *seated* is simple past
B. *had taken* is past perfect
C. *have been seated* is passive / indicative present perfect
D. *having seated* is the past participle.

So, the answer is most likely given as *A* because of the tense agreement. But it is not good grammar.